# 2.0 cypher query with counts

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database with people and cities.  Is this query doing what I think it is doing

```
MATCH (c:City)-->(p:People)
RETURN c,count(p);
```

I want this query to be spitting back the city c with the count of the people in that city.  However, the count is only one.  This is either a problem with my loader or my query.  Is the query giving me back what I think it is?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your original query needs to change the direction.

```
MATCH (n:City)<--(p:Person) 
RETURN n,count(p)
```

You need to have person going "into" city, and this returns the correct results for your example, as your example has 3 people "LIVES_IN" New York and 1 people "LIVES_IN" Boston, and that is what the query is returning in the [console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=199rob).